# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Realm

Tags: android, gradle, realm, android-studio-3.0

Realm in android get error:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/realm/Realm$1$1;
```

Congig:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
```

I tried clean project rebuild project not happend

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of Realm?

Comment: Why **are** you using version 0.87.5 **and** 4.2.0 at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this problem like so:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

//compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5' // <-- removed
//annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5' // <-- removed
```

Comment: I do not need dependency?

Comment: how so?)))) I spent so much time to find. and in the document there is an example I have seen 0.72.Х

Comment: The Realm Gradle Plugin adds the dependencies for you